# Why can't I log in to Evernote when I am using Skitch?

Tags: ssl, evernote

I am running Evernote Skitch, latest version, on Windows 7 but when I attempt to log in to my Evernote account in Skitch, I receive the following error:

Warning: Could not establish a valid SSL connection to the Evernote service

Does anyone have any ideas on how to correct this? I can log in through my installed version of Evernote OK.

Comment: Did it work before?

Comment: This was the first time I installed Skitch so no prior history to reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is/was a known bug. [Version 2.2.2.154](http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/39501-cant-login-on-desktop/?p=216396) should include the bug fix for this.